# How do I limit an input in python so it will only allow 0 or 1's?

Tags: python

Ive got a binary converter in python and I want to know how to limit my input to certain numbers only, in this case. Only 1's or 0's. So 101010001 is valid but 44 is not for example. Thanks.

Comment: can you show what you have tried?

Comment: What do you want to happen if the user tries to enter an invalid number?

Comment: The program converts and gives a totally random  number that is not binary. `

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can also try to attempt to convert it to integer as binary, and print message if that fails.

```
query = raw_input("enter binary number ")

try:
    is_bin = int(query,2)
    is_bin = True
    print "correct number"
except ValueError:
    is_bin = False
    print "not a binary number"
```

Comment: the most pythonic answer so far

Comment: Well, you beat me to it.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use [Regular Expressions](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html). You need to make it match 0 or 1 in any position. The regex in this case is `[01]*`

Comment: That matches a string of 0s, 1s, and `|`s.

Comment: The | is a metacharacter, it's used as an OR operation.

Comment: Not inside `[`. Individual characters are already implicitly OR'd in a bracket expression.

Answer (score 0):

You can't prevent the string from being input, but you can match it against a regular expression after the fact and take appropriate action. Raising an exception is one possibility.

```
import re

if not re.match("^[01]*$", input_value):
    raise ValueError("Not a binary number")
```

Answer (score 0):

Without regular expressions:

```
if all(ch in "01" for ch in input_str):
    raise ValueError("'{}' is not valid binary".format(input_str))
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions work, but so does simple iteration:

```
def binaryConverter(input_value):
    for c in input_value:
        if c not in '01':
            # do something here, for example:
            raise ValueError("Not a binary number")
    return int(input_value, 2)
```

If you just want a simple binary conversion, you can just use `int(input_value, 2)` This will automatically raise a ValueError for any characters that aren't 0 or 1.

Comment: Why iterate over the string, rather than just catching the exception raised by `int`, or simply letting that exception propagate?

Comment: By the same logic, why use regexes? When we posted our answers, we didn't know what his desired behavior/output was, this is just an alternative, which -- to me -- is clearer and simpler than a regex.

Comment: My point is that you are duplicating work already done by `int`, not that iterating is inferior to a regular expression. If you are going to call `int`, it already raises an exception if the input is invalid.

Comment: I completely agree, but what if he wanted to return or modify the problematic character(s)? re and iteration let you do that, not so with just `int`